# Proguard configuration to leave some inner classes alone

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I'm trying to configure the proguard.cfg file in Eclipse to leave alone (don't rename class or class members) for some inner classes.

So in my case the inner classes are all in com.mycorp.android.mapper.APIHelper

I tried this:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers public class com.mycorp.android.mapper.APIHelper$*
```

But that doesn't seem to work. What is the right syntax?

**Edit:** I've also tried having these classes implement a blank interface and then tried:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * implements com.mycorp.android.JSONSerializable {
    *;
}
```

No luck with that either.

Comment: Update: Problem seems to be with GSON and Proguard. Added a few more gson specific lines to config and getting farther but not perfect yet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify which members you want to keep. If it's all of them I believe the following should work. This won't keep the APIHelper class itself, only the inner classes and their members.

```
-keep public class com.mycorp.android.mapper.APIHelper$* {
   *;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `-keep` instead of `-keepclasseswithmembers` (based on the Proguard documentation [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html)).

Comment: Nope, I've tried it with just -keep and no luck there either.

Comment: Interesting .. maybe you can check the [Class Specifications](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#classspecification) section more closely or see the [android application example](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#androidapplication) for some ideas.

Comment: Problem seems to be with using GSON and Proguard together. I've gotten a bit further than before now by adding some gson config entries to Proguard. Still not perfect.